# using flux architecture pattern with server-client application

Tags: client-server, flux, electron

I'm trying to build a Desktop app using Github's [Electron Framework](https://github.com/atom/electron), which separates a "main" io.js process from a "render" JS process (BrowserWindow). I think of the "main"/"renderer" processes as analogous to a server and client (let me know if this is mistaken).

I'm confused about how to apply the Flux pattern in this situation. Some interactions with the UI don't require sending data to the main process (i.e. the [TODO-list example](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-todomvc/) )

1) Does that mean the Dispatcher object should reside with the renderer process?
2) Suppose the main process receives an incoming event/action from the filesystem. To update the dispatcher, would the main process have to implement an ActionCreator to create an action, then send the Action over IPC/RPC to the dispatcher on the renderer/client process? 
3) If (2) is true, does that mean that action creators and stores are also implemented on the main/server side?

It feels strange to have the "First Responder"/"Delegate" within the context of a renderer process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, some more reading helped me figure it out. Flux was intended to be primarily a client-side application pattern.

The following diagram illustrates the typical use case, and how the server and its associated state is somewhat disconnected from the client-side Flux logic.

[image: Flux TODO-list architecture]

In other words, Flux on the client does not solve the problem of managing state and components on the web-api side. For client-side applications that are tightly coupled to server-side code (like Electron apps, iPython notebook, NW.js apps), it might make sense to implement the dispatcher similar to Cocoa's delegation pattern rather in the UI thread.

Comment: Would it be possible to put the Dispatcher and Store on the main process and leave the React Views and Action Creators on the render process? Or would this not make sense?